# Does torch.utils.tensorboard need installation of Tensorflow?

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

I'm new to pytorch and I wonder if using tensorboard on pytorch needs tensorflow as a dependency. Moreover, except for tensorboard, what are other options for training curve visualization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed tensorboard is part of tensorflow, but it does not depend on it.
You can safely install only tensorboard (e.g, [`pip install tensorboard`](https://pypi.org/project/tensorboard/)) or [`conda install -c conda-forge tensorboard`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorboard)) and use `torch.utils.tensorboard`.