# import torch.utils.tensorboard causes tensorflow warnings

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547471/does-torch-utils-tensorboard-need-installation-of-tensorflow) tensorboard is part of tensorflow but does not depend on it. One can use it in pytorch such as

```py
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
```

It is, however, annoying that this import causes a long trace of tensorflow related warnings

```bash
2024-03-28 12:11:43.296359: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:110] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.                                                                              
2024-03-28 12:11:43.331928: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-03-28 12:11:43.970865: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
```

I wonder if this is necessary and / or how they can be (safely?) muted.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that is not based on importing tensorflow (which I dont use) but allows muting [through environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40871012/9659620):

Simply add this line to the beginning of your script.

```py
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'  # FATAL
```

This should work for any `tensorflow > 1.14`

Answer (score 0):

If the warnings do not affect your code execution or performance, you can choose to ignore them.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning)
```

Comment: thank you, this is good idea, however, this will ignore all warnings from all modules. It would be better to simply ignore tensorflow warnings